# How to match strings with regex to know of the first two words of a letter has their first later capitalised

Tags: java, regex

I have a String `" Karren Warren, this is a very good product "`  and I want to use a regex to return true whenever the first letter in the first word is capitalized and the first word in the second letter is capitalized. Meaning the two words whose first letters are capitalized has to be consecutive.
So in the example given above, the regex would return true because `K` is capitalized and `W` is capitalized. Conversely, it would return false in the scenario when the text is  `Karren warren, Kindly check this out`

I used this pattern `([A-Z]\w+\s){2}`but it keeps on returning false.

Comment: Just confirming - your input may contain leading spaces?

Comment: Yes it may contain leading space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
^\s*[A-Z][^\s]+\s+[A-Z]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/B8XDKg/1/

Answer (score 1):

To match all uppercase letters that have a lowercase variant, you could use `\p{Lu}`. If you don't want to cross newlines, you can use `\h` to match horizontal whitespace chars, as `\s` could also match a newline.

```
^\p{Lu}\S+\h+\p{Lu}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mSCRP9/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/4JDcI8)

In Java with the doubled backslashes

```
String regex = "^\\p{Lu}\\S+\\h+\\p{Lu}";
```